# Dockerfile for on and off proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy, docker-compose

I run `docker-compose up -d` to build and run two containers

```
-- docker-compose.yml

node:
  build: .
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "8080"
    - "9000:9000"
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2
  ports:
    - "27017"
```

In my Dockerfile I set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` ENV vars

```
-- Dockerfile
ENV http_proxy http://proxy-address.co.uk:80/
ENV https_proxy http://proxy-address.co.uk:80/
```

I need to be able to run this though on and off a proxy so ideally it would be great if I could just pass the VARS on the command line if I need to set them.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anybody else this is what i ended up doing to resolve this. So `docker-compose` can read ENV vars from the host machine.

```
--Added the following to my Dockerfile
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
  args:
    http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
    https_proxy: ${http_proxy}
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "8080"
    - "9000:9000"
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
  ports:
    - "27017"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

One of them:

You can put var to .env file

```
http_proxy=http://proxy-address.co.uk:80/
```

and use in compose

```
node:
  build: .
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "8080"
    - "9000:9000"
  environment:
    http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
```

Details
[Doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i was just wondering if this sets the var whether i am on or off proxy ? and also this does not seem work

Comment: im not entirely sure you have understood the question ?